# Send current URL automatically through Axios Intercepter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, xmlhttprequest

I would like to send the current URL in the header automatically through an Axios instance. The reason is the backend will parse the originating URL and extract useful information from it and I don't want clients to keep adding it in the header manually.

I wanted to use `referrer` from the header, but this seems unreliable. The Axios instance will be used from React pages and components. Possibly how to do this through an Interceptor or maybe a context provider?

Is there a reliable way to do this? Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I so impressed with your question and i hope my solution can help your solve problem

```js
instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  // Get the current URL
  const currentURL = window.location.href;

  // Add the current URL to the request headers
  config.headers['X-Current-URL'] = currentURL;

  return config;
}, (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Export the modified Axios instance
export default instance;
```

In this example, we're adding the current URL to the request headers using the key 'X-Current-URL'. You can change this key according to your backend's requirements.

Note:Note: The window.location.href in the example assumes that you're running the React application in a browser environment. If you're using server-side rendering or other environments where window may not be available